# Search Users by Assigned Role

Tags: youtrack

I'm trying to find a way to export a list of users with a specific role assigned.

So far I have went through all the KB articles and the forum, but unsuccessfully

Would anyone know how to do that?

Comment: RDBMS? Can you provide an [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Users** page and write `access(with: role_name)` in the filter bar. It will show all users that have a `role_name` in any project.

Comment: You can also do it via REST API: `GET https://example.youtrack.cloud/hub/api/rest/users?fields=id,name,login&query=access(with: role_name)`